# Formatting bold text XML

Tags: html, xml, formatting, mechanicalturk

I am using MTURKS to create the following survey question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuestionForm xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
  <Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>1</QuestionIdentifier>
    <QuestionContent>
            <Text>${question}</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
      <SelectionAnswer>
        <MinSelectionCount>1</MinSelectionCount>
        <MaxSelectionCount>1</MaxSelectionCount>
        <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
        <Selections>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>${choice2}</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Subject 1: Math</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>${choice1}</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Subject 2: Science</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>Alt1</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Alt1</Text>
          </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>noneoftheabove</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Subject 3: PE</Text>
          </Selection>
        </Selections>
      </SelectionAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
```

Ideally I'd like this formatted so it appears as a single question with text in the answer that is bolded (e.g., bold the word subject in each response). I'd also like to add text between answer choices 2 and 3 so that the user sees the following:
$question

**Academic subjects**

1. **Subject 1:** Math
2. **Subject 2:** Science

**Other subjects**

3. **Subject 3:** PE

When I try to next formatting objections within the  prompt, using this code:

```
<Text><b>Subject 2:</b> Science</Text>
```

I get an error that says:

```
[ERROR] Error creating HIT 1 (B: x0): [-1,-1] cvc-type.3.1.2: Element 'Text' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children].
```

I also get the same error (shown above) when I try:

```
       </Selection>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>${choice1}</SelectionIdentifier>
            <Text>Subject 2: Science</Text>
          </Selection>
     <text>Academic Subjects</text>
          <Selection>
            <SelectionIdentifier>Alt1</SelectionIdentifier>
```

In order to intersperse text between item responses.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code?  I should state that HTML is a type of XML, and the <b> or <strong> tags can be used to render text as bold, q.v. the following article for more information http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/255366/why-are-the-b-and-i-tags-deprecated

Comment: You have the phrase “I try to next formatting objections within the prompt” in your question above the error message and I do not understand what that means, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry... edited for clarity.

Comment: Thanks... my revised code looks like: `<Text><strong>Subject 2:</strong> Science</Text>`, but, I get the same error message. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `<FormattedContent>` tag as in this example:

```
<Selection>
  <SelectionIdentifier>${choice1}</SelectionIdentifier>
  <FormattedContent><![CDATA[
    <b>Subject 2:</b> Science
  ]]></FormattedContent>
</Selection>
```

You can read more about the `<FormattedContent>` tag [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_FormattedContentXHTMLArticle.html) on the AWS Turk website.

Comment: That makes sense but how do I format the response options so that plain text is interspersed... I've updated my question to clarify this point.